# ASP.NET Core 6 Authentication via Azure AD: customize login path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm working on a POC to create an Asp.Net Core 6 Web App with the ability to authenticate users via an Azure AD identity server AND via a custom local user DB.

I need to create a Login page where the user can choose between the two authentication methods ('/Login/Login').

When I try to load a not-anonymous page (controller/action) the system redirect me automatically to the Microsoft login page instead of my custom page (/Login/Login).

I have tried some solutions like:

```
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {...}, configureCookieAuthenticationOptions: options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login");
})
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "user.read" })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

or

```
    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login");
    });
```

But nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Comment: Thank You but there they talk about the Authentication Filter for an API for .NET 3/5. I don't see anything about user redirecting. I was thinking about make a custom filter but I don't get why I should do it if there are options for this kind of features.
Ps: I forgot to mention that the Login Path works with the AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) only

Comment: Redirecting is part of the box for "Controller Action".

Comment: I don't get it: are you talking about the ability to control the flow directly from a controller action without any global filter or controller/action filter? That is not a way.

Comment: The picture in link has two boxes.  First for authentication second for Controller Action.  The Controller Action is everything that is not part of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow;

***To redirect to your custom login page with microsoft identity using ASP.NET core application you can add the following to your `startup.cs`***

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
            options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
        });

        // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

For complete setup please refer this [***GitHub link***](https://github.com/amanmcse/Document/blob/main/AzureADB2B_AuthApp.md) by @*amanmcse* .

*For more information please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***External Authentication with ASP.NET Identity***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/cutting-edge-external-authentication-with-asp-net-identity)* .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
       });
```

In Startup file. This will add second auth scheme for your app, so don't forget to add second schema when you are configuring 'Authorize' attribute